# How do you update a user role to be an admin role via Drush sql-query?

Tags: drush, users

I know the following User ID 2524 and the Name is Tester. And the role to be an admin is 3. What command is needed to make a user an admin using only the the drush terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a reason to execute a sql query, when this can be as simple as

```
drush user-add-role "administrator" --uid=2524
```

To see more options with command type

```
drush help user-add-role
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sql statement:

**drush sql-query 'insert into users_roles (uid, rid) values (2524, 3)'**

The **users_roles** table is where user and role data is stored. Initially I thought the roles was stored in the users or roles table.